# How do I stop CKEditor from inserting close tags after empty (self-close) MathML tags?

Tags: ckeditor, mathml

[Proper MathML notation of repeating decimals](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-MathML3-20081117/chapter3.html#presm.repeatdec) calls for an empty `<mline />` tag:

`<math><mover align="right"><mn>0.16</mn><mline spacing="6" /></mover></math>`

CKEditor doesn't recognize this as a proper empty tag and unhelpfully inserts a closing tag `</mline>` and messes up MathJax interpretation:

`<math><mover align="right"><mn>0.16</mn><mline spacing="3"></mline></mover></math>`

This has implications for use of MathML's other empty tags, like `<maligngroup/>` and `<malignmark/>`.

Answer (score 1):

Solution was to add `mline` to CKEditors list of `$empty` tags in ckeditor_config.js:

`CKEDITOR.dtd.$empty['mline'] = 1;`

Ended up adding a few more just in case:

```
_(['mline', 'mspace', 'maligngroup', 'malignmark', 'msline']).each(function(tag, index){
  CKEDITOR.dtd.$empty[tag] = 1;
})
```